# What is the term used to describe the aesthetic value of the wearing effect that comes from usage of an object?

Tags: single-word-requests

The examples typically cited are well-worn bicycles, the steering wheel on a vintage car, a leather wallet, etc. Seems related to patina but not the same. This may be a neologism.

E.g. "The ______ of the steering wheel speaks to the years of use and loving care John put into his Roadster."

Interesting, [here](http://lovelybike.blogspot.mx/2012/06/aesthetics-of-use.html?m=1) they call it "aesthetics of use" but I'm certain there is a single term.

Comment: You might consider *age-value* but I haven't seen it applied to all kind of items. [This source](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/citd/holtorf/6.9.html) uses the term for monuments.

Answer (score 1):

The term ***[patina](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patina)*** carries the connotation you are looking for:

> - the sheen on a surface that is caused by much handling.

Collins Dictionary

Comment: +1 re definition #2.  Definition #1 also provides an attractive and convenient alternative for coin dealers to use, along with “toned,” when describing and trying to sell their corroded or tarnished merchandise!

Comment: *Patina* was given by OP already and he is looking for another word. He is looking for a word to define the value. *Patina* doesn't define the value but it might define where that value is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha sometimes a good night's sleep is all you need to dislodge the answer. Of course, I then had to struggle to find this post again. I remembered: It's "**beausage**"!

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Beausage
http://www.ecovelo.info/2008/06/03/a-deep-patina/

Comment: Is this word actually used in the wild?